# "undefined name" error when building a map within a class

Tags: python, class, maps, undefined

I'm trying to build a class in which I have to build a map, but when I define a function to build it I get an "undefined name" error.

```
from location import Location,PAREDE,CHAO,STOCK

class Map:

    def __init__(self, row, col,grid):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.grid= grid
        self.map= build_map(grid, row , col)  'here it's says the name build_map is undefined'
```

This the function that creates the map:

```
    def build_map(grid, row , col): 
        mapa=[]
        for r in range(0, row):
            line=[]
            for c in range(0, col):
                type_location = grid[r][c]
                location = None
                if type_location == PAREDE:
                    location = Location(r,c, 'PAREDE')
                elif type_location == CHAO:
                    location = Location(r,c, 'CHAO')
                elif type_location == STOCK:
                    location = Location(r,c, 'STOCK')

                line.append(location)
            mapa.append(line)
        return mapa
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What, exactly, is your error? Post the full error message including the stack trace. Post the code that actually produces the error.

Answer (score 0):

Call `build_map` with `self.build_map`. `build_map` is referring to an outer scope - in which you don't have a `build_map` function defined.

You can do some separate reading on modules here: docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html To solve your problem, either bring the build_map function into the class, add self as a parameter and call it with self.build_map or just have the build_map method imported or defined in the same file that you have that class.

Comment: I don't think that `build_map` is a method of `Map`. If it was, there would be a `self` parameter.

Comment: Ah, good point. With that being said, ```build_map``` isn't accessible to the class - so he might have it another module.

Comment: Yes build_map is not a method, but self.map is. So I'll have to create a module? what is a module?

Comment: You can do some separate reading on that here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html To solve your problem, either bring the build_map function into the class, add self as a parameter and call it with self.build_map or just have the build_map method imported or defined in the same file that you have that class.

Comment: Cheers man, definitely take the time to read up on modules - it will take you very far with python. Could you also mark this as the answer.